# Discover devices vendor and model on a local network

Tags: javascript, android, networking

I need to find out if it's possible and if so, what is the API for that.

> The required  scenario:
>
> > 1. connect to a wifi network.
> > 2. from an android app or using javascript from a webpage find out the make and model of devices that are connected to the same router.

I found a way to find the IP addresses, and I saw that Find app can see the manufacturers, but can't tell if it's a mobile device, a tablet, a laptop or a printer.

I thought that a possible way would be to use jmDNS (which I can't get my android project to compile with), and service discovery, but I'm not sure that it will tell me if the device is a tablet or a smartphone.

For Android I can also think of the linux build number to search against a device list compatible with that build. However, I'm not sure about Apple devices.

Is there a way to do that or am I wasting my time?
If there is, will it work in Android or with JS?

Thanks.

Comment: SNMP may help you - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol, this can be a start, However, I never did this...

Comment: I don't see in SNMP implementation libraries a way or an example to help me connect to a router and poll it for the connected devices. is there a way to do it? the documentation isn't good enough, and the sample application assumes I have a decent knowledge of SNMP.